# Implement Payment Process With Quickbook(Intuit Payment)

Tags: php, intuit-partner-platform

I want to implement Quickbook payment process for e-commerce site. i search lot but cant find proper solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need a test/development merchant account, instructions are provided [here](http://www.consolibyte.com/docs/index.php/QuickBooks_Merchant_Services#Getting_Started) to get one. Otherwise, use your actual Intuit username/password for the rest of the steps.

Follow the instructions [on our QuickBooks wiki](http://www.consolibyte.com/docs/index.php/QuickBooks_Merchant_Services#Getting_started_with_the_.27Desktop.27_communication_model) to register in DESKTOP mode.

After registration, you should have an App Login, App ID, and a Connection Ticket. You'll get the App Login and App ID from the actual registration process, and then the Connection Ticket after you go through the short connection process.

Download the [QuickBooks PHP DevKit](https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php) from GitHub: https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php

Look at this example file: docs/example_merchant_services.php ([click here for direct link to code on GitHub](https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php/blob/master/docs/example_merchant_service.php))

Fill in your App Login / Connection Ticket.

Read through the rest of that docs/example_merchant_service.php file for examples of how to charge credit cards, authorize credit cards, etc.

There are a few other examples in the docs/ directory (example_merchant_service_wallet.php, etc.) which also show how to store credit cards with Intuit in a PCI-compliant manner, etc.

Your resulting code should end up looking something like:

```
<?php

// Include the QuickBooks files
require_once 'QuickBooks.php';

$dsn = null;
$path_to_private_key_and_certificate = null;
$application_login = 'qbms.consolibyte.com';
$connection_ticket = 'TGT-157-p3PyZPoH3DtieLSh4ykp6Q';

// Create an instance of the MerchantService object 
$MS = new QuickBooks_MerchantService(
    $dsn, 
    $path_to_private_key_and_certificate, 
    $application_login,
    $connection_ticket);

// Now, let's create a credit card object, and authorize an amount agains the card
$name = 'Keith Palmer';
$number = '5105105105105100';
$expyear = date('Y');
$expmonth = date('m');
$address = '56 Cowles Road';
$postalcode = '06279';
$cvv = null;

// Create the CreditCard object
$Card = new QuickBooks_MerchantService_CreditCard($name, $number, $expyear, $expmonth, $address, $postalcode, $cvv);

// We're going to authorize $295.00
$amount = 295.0;

if ($Transaction = $MS->authorize($Card, $amount))
{
    print('Card authorized!' . "\n");
    print_r($Transaction);  
}
```

Comment: Thanks for valuable help.

Answer (score 2):

You can check the following site.

https://developer.intuit.com/docs/030_qbms

If you have any specific qts, then please raise a support ticket.

https://developer.intuit.com/Support/Incident

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**For Developer:**
In the document suggested above you will find the step to generate key. Let me give you more input on this as I have faced some question during my development.

***Step 3:***

> Generate a CSR on your server. You can do this with the following two
>   commands from a *nix shell prompt, or using Cygwin on Windows. The
>   [Common Name] for the CSR should be in the form of:
>   your-https-hostname.com:your-application-login. You should not enter
>   an e-mail address when prompted. You should not enter a password.
>
> ```
> openssl genrsa -out host.key 1024
> openssl req -new -nodes -key host.key -out host.csr
> ```

***Suggestions:***

If you got confused or don't know what exactly need to do with this commands then here is the solution if you are php developer.

First create a private key using following php code, 
You should use http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php to execute above command. It is recommended to create private key out of the public_html or www folder of your site for security reason. To do so, you may write a new *key.php* file in you site root folder (public_html/key.php)

```
shell_exec('openssl genrsa -out ../host.key 1024');
```

After successfully executing this code you will find host.key in your server out side of public_html folder.

Download this file using FTP or cpanel and do following steps in your local systems terminal (for *nix users). You will ask to enter some information about your country and all that, just leave them blank by giving '.' - this is necessary otherwise you will not able to get signed certificate.

```
gunjan@gunjan:/var/www/html$ openssl req -new -nodes -key host.key -out host.csr
You are about to be asked to enter information that will be incorporated
into your certificate request.
What you are about to enter is what is called a Distinguished Name or a DN.
There are quite a few fields but you can leave some blank
For some fields there will be a default value,
If you enter '.', the field will be left blank.
-----
Country Name (2 letter code) [AU]:.
State or Province Name (full name) [Some-State]:.
Locality Name (eg, city) []:.
Organization Name (eg, company) [Internet Widgits Pty Ltd]:.
Organizational Unit Name (eg, section) []:.
Common Name (e.g. server FQDN or YOUR name) []:<very_important_step_copy_CN_from_developer_account>
Email Address []:.

Please enter the following 'extra' attributes
to be sent with your certificate request
A challenge password []:.
An optional company name []:.
```

After that you will get csr signed certificate string. Copy it and save to .txt file, this is going to be used to generate **.pem** file, which will be used in merchant connection.