# Implement Recurring Payments with Quick Books (Inituit Payments)

Tags: php, intuit-partner-platform

I trying to implement a recurring payments for a web application with inituit payments.

I was searching a lot but couldnt find much detail documentation which has a good flow. Is there any specific links or examples which I can see.

I came across this question it is a good one but not recurring payments again.

[Implement Payment Process With Quickbook(Intuit Payment)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19200339/implement-payment-process-with-quickbookintuit-payment)

I want my app to obtain the payment details from the client and process it via the gateway.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found this as the starting point for the payments

https://developer.intuit.com/docs/030_qbms

but still wanting to find the XML requests